# SugarCRM removing initial welcome and information entry screen for new users

Tags: sugarcrm

When user initially signs in, they are presented with many Sugar advertisements and information screens to fill out.
Can we configure out this not to show the user and directly go to home screen.

The similar question is posted in SugarCRM forums also but no response.

http://www.sugarcrm.com/forums/showthread.php?t=69735

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a check box on the "Create User" screen "User Wizard Prompt:" uncheck this.

Comment: Do you know how to do same thing programmatically?